# Spring boot admin giving error as Unknownhost exception while registering client

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am getting below error when I am trying to register Spring boot admin client

```
Failed to register application as Application (name=JSONXML Micro Service, managementUrl=http://jsonxml-wrapper/jsonxml/actuator, healthUrl=http://jsonxml-wrapper/jsonxml/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://jsonxml-wrapper/jsonxml)
```

at spring-boot-admin ([http://phaseiv-admin-server/phaseivadminserver/instances]):
I/O error on POST request for "http://phaseiv-admin-server/phaseivadminserver/instances":
phaseiv-admin-server; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: phaseiv-admin-server

My Admin server is up on URL : https://XXX/phaseivadminserver/#/applications

I am using below dependency

spring-boot-starter-parent =2.2.7

Spring boot admin server= 2.3.1

spring boot admin client=2.3.1